# How do i deploy a Sveltekit SSG app on shared hosting

Tags: sveltekit, shared-hosting

Trying to deploy an ssg svelkit app to shared hosting without using node as a server ! So I built my app and now I am left with an _app\immutable folder that has an assets, chunks, entry and nodes folder. There is no html or js file to launch from.

How do I use this?

I have already tried deploying with a node adapter but the hosting company were not very helpfull